# Dust.js using the same partial many times on the same page

Tags: node.js, partials, dust.js

I have a parent template that receives the following context:

```
{
users: 
[
    {
        userId: "18288128",
        group: "User 1 Group Name",
        userVideos: [{ id: 1, name: "Video1"},
                     { id: 2, name: "Video2"},
                     { id: 3, name: "Video3"}]
    },
    {
        userId: "1232412",
        group: "User 2 Group Name",
        userVideos: [{ id: 4, name: "Video93"},
                     { id: 5, name: "Video384"},
                     { id: 6, name: "Video483"}]
    },
    {
        userId: "1231231",
        group: "User 3 Group Name",
        userVideos: [{ id: 7, name: "VideoA"},
                     { id: 8, name: "VideoB"},
                     { id: 9, name: "VideoC"}]
    }
]
}
```

This is the parent template:

```
{#users}
  {! Here I want to add the partial video_list passing the correct parameters (uniqueId, groupName and the video list) !}
  {>video_list /}
{/users}
```

This is the partial video_list:

```
UniqueId: {uniqueId}{~n}
GroupName: {groupName}{~n}
<ul>
  {#videos}
<li>{name}</li>{~n}
  {/videos}
</ul>
```

How can I call the partial from the parent template e pass the parameters uniqueId=userId, groupName=group and videos=userVideos (this is a list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partials accept parameters, so you can do something like this:

```
{>video_list uniqueId=userId groupName=group videos=userVideos/}
```